# How do I test the useEffect React hook when it includes a 'document.addEventListener' inside it?

Tags: react-hooks, addeventlistener, use-effect, react-testing-library, use-ref

Here is my `useEffect` Call:

```
    const ref = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {

        const clickListener = (e: MouseEvent) => {
            if (ref.current.contains(e.target as Node)) return;
            closePopout();
        }

        document.addEventListener('click', clickListener);
        
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', clickListener);
            closePopout();
        }

    }, [ref, closePopout]);
```

I'm using this to control a popout menu. When you click on the menu icon to bring up the menu it will open it up. When you click anywhere that isn't the popout it closes the popout. Or when the component gets cleaned up it closes the popout as well.

I'm using `@testing-library/react-hooks` to render the hooks:

https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library

We are also using TypeScript so if there is any TS specific stuff that would be very helpful as well.

Hopefully this is enough info. If not let me know.

**EDIT:**

I am using two companion hooks. I'm doing quite a bit in it and I was hoping to simplify the question but here is the full code for the hooks. The top hook (useWithPopoutMenu) is called when the PopoutMenu component is rendered. The bottom one is called inside the body of the PopoutMenu component.

```
// for use when importing the component
export const useWithPopoutMenu = () => {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpenTo] = useState(false);
    const [h, setHorizontal] = useState(0);
    const [v, setVertical] = useState(0);
    const close = useCallback(() => setIsOpenTo(false), []);

    return {
        isOpen,
        menuEvent: {h, v, isOpen, close} as PopoutMenuEvent,
        open: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
            setIsOpenTo(true);
            setHorizontal(e.clientX);
            setVertical(e.clientY);
        },
        close
    };
}

type UsePopoutMenuArgs = {
    menuEvent: PopoutMenuEvent
    padding: number
    tickPosition: number
    horizontalFix: number | null
    verticalFix: number | null
    hPosition: number
    vPosition: number
    borderColor: string
}

// for use inside the component its self 
export const usePopoutMenu = ({
    menuEvent,
    padding,
    tickPosition,
    horizontalFix,
    verticalFix,
    hPosition,
    vPosition,
    borderColor
}: UsePopoutMenuArgs) => {
    const ref = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClick = (e: MouseEvent) => {
            if (ref.current.contains(e.target as Node)) return;
            menuEvent.close();
        }
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
            menuEvent.close();
        }
    }, [menuEvent.close, ref]);
    
    
    const menuContainerStyle = useMemo(() => {
        const left = horizontalFix || menuEvent.h;
        const top = verticalFix || menuEvent.v;
        return {
            padding,
            left,
            top, 
            marginLeft: hPosition,
            marginTop: vPosition,
            border: `1px solid ${borderColor}`
        }

    }, [
        padding, 
        horizontalFix, 
        verticalFix, 
        menuEvent,
        hPosition,
        vPosition,
        borderColor
    ]);

    const backgroundArrowStyle = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            marginLeft: `-${padding + 6}px`,
            marginTop: 4 - padding + tickPosition,
        }
    },[padding, tickPosition]);

    const foregroundArrowStyle = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            marginLeft: `-${padding + 5}px`,
            marginTop: 4 - padding + tickPosition,
        }
    },[padding, tickPosition]);

    return {
        ref,
        menuContainerStyle,
        backgroundArrowStyle,
        foregroundArrowStyle
    }
}
```

Here is the component:

```
type PopoutMenuProps = {
    children: React.ReactChild | React.ReactChild[]  // normal props.children
    menuEvent: PopoutMenuEvent
    padding?: number                                 // padding that goes around the 
    tickPosition?: number                            // how far down the tick is from the top
    borderColor?: string                             // border color
    bgColor?: string                                 // background color 
    horizontalFix?: number | null
    verticalFix?: number | null
    vPosition?: number
    hPosition?: number
}

const Container = styled.div`
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 10;
`;

const Arrow = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
`;

const PopoutMenu = ({
    children,
    menuEvent,
    padding = 16,
    tickPosition = 10,
    borderColor = Style.color.gray.medium,
    bgColor = Style.color.white,
    vPosition = -20,
    hPosition = 10,
    horizontalFix = null,
    verticalFix = null
}: PopoutMenuProps) => {
    
    const binding = usePopoutMenu({
        menuEvent, 
        padding, 
        tickPosition, 
        vPosition, 
        hPosition, 
        horizontalFix, 
        verticalFix,
        borderColor
    });

    return (
        <Container ref={binding.ref} style={binding.menuContainerStyle}>
            <Arrow style={binding.backgroundArrowStyle}>
                <Left color={borderColor} />
            </Arrow>
            <Arrow style={binding.foregroundArrowStyle}>
                <Left color={bgColor} />
            </Arrow>
            {children}
        </Container>
    );
}

export default PopoutMenu;
```

Usage is something like this:

```
const Parent () => {
   const popoutMenu = useWithPopoutMenu();
   return (
      ...
      <ComponentThatOpensThePopout onClick={popoutMenu.open}>...
      ...
      {popoutMenu.isOpen && <PopoutMenu menuEvent={menuEvent}>PopoutMenu Content</PopoutMenu>}
   );
}
```

Comment: can you include the complete code for the hook? `closePopout` definition is missing

Comment: @Doug hopefully that helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to test the hook in isolation?

Testing the component that consumes the hook would be much easier and it would also be a more realistic test, pseudo code below:

```js
render(<PopoverConsumer />);

userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Menu' });
expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toBeInTheDocument();

userEvent.click(screen.getByText('somewhere outside');
expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: I tried something like this but I can try again. I am not sure I fleshed out every possibility.